# TestNG retry class doesn't run @BeforeClass nor @AfterClass methods

Tags: java, testng

I have a test like this:

```
public class Test1 extends AbstractTest {

    @Test(retryAnalyzer=Retry.class)
    public void test(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " running.");
        Assert.fail();
    }

}
```

With setup and teardown methods like this:

```
public class AbstractTest {

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " initialized");
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " complete");
    }

}
```

And a retry class like this:

```
public class Retry implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int retryCount = 0;
    private int maxRetryCount = 1;

    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

But the setup and tearDown methods don't run before and after the test method despite having set alwaysRun to true.  Here's some console output:

```
tests.Test1 initialized
tests.Test1 running.
tests.Test1 running.
tests.Test1 complete
```

Why is this?  How can I get them to run each time the test retries?

Comment: What you describe is how testng is supposed to work. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotations 
`org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod`
and
`org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod` will behave as you require - in other words, run the setup and tear down code before each invocation of the test method, regardless of whether or not it was triggered by a retry.

Full documentation in the TestNG javadoc for [@BeforeMethod](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/BeforeMethod.html) and [@AfterMethod](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/AfterMethod.html).

Comment: Using \@BeforeMethod and \@AfterMethod works the way I need it to.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is as per design.

> `@BeforeClass`: The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked.

- In your case it is `setup`, it will print **initialized**.
- `setup` will never run again until the same class is reloaded for execution.

> `@AfterClass`: The annotated method will be run after all the test methods in the current class have been run.

- In your case it is `tearDown`, it will run after all the test methods including all retry attempts in the current class have been run and print **complete**.

Note: `retry(ITestResult result)` returns true if the **test method has to be retried**, false otherwise. So whether test methods have to be retried or not will be governed by the `retry` method. Behaviour of `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` remains unchanged.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

As of now TestNG doesnot support retry of Configuration methods (e.g beforeMethod , beforeTest etc.. ) https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1444

if configuration method fails tests will skip/fail .

you can use some logic to retry your code inside @BeforeMethod or @BeforeTest ..

```
int count = 0;
int maxTries = 3;

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(){
while(true) {
try {
// Some Code
// break out of loop, or return, on success
} catch (SomeException e) {
// handle exception
if (++count == maxTries) throw e;
}
}
}
```

Comment: No longer accurate with IConfigurable interface.